# Unable to publish the chrome extension to public

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am trying to publish an chrome extension with following manifest file.

Every time I publish my app it is getting rejected.

**Updated**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Aiwozo",
  "description": "AI Work Zone Web Automation Extension is an component developed for browser interaction to implement automation on web applications.",
  "version": "1.1",
  "icons": {
    "16":"static/activate_icons/Aiwozo16.png",
    "32":"static/activate_icons/Aiwozo32.png",
    "64": "static/activate_icons/Aiwozo64.png",
    "128":"static/activate_icons/Aiwozo128.png"
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16":"static/activate_icons/Aiwozo16.png",
      "32":"static/activate_icons/Aiwozo32.png",
      "64": "static/activate_icons/Aiwozo64.png",
      "128":"static/activate_icons/Aiwozo128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Artificial Intelligence Work Zone"
  },
  "permissions": ["nativeMessaging", "<all_urls>"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "css/general.css", "static/activate_icons/AIwozo16.png", "static/activate_icons/AIwozo32.png", "static/activate_icons/AIwozo64.png", "static/activate_icons/AIwozo128.png", "static/deactivate_icons/AIwozo16.png", "static/deactivate_icons/AIwozo32.png", "static/deactivate_icons/AIwozo64.png", "static/deactivate_icons/AIwozo128.png"]
}
```

Comment: You have extremely broad permissions and "do not use unless absolutely required" practices (e.g. whitelisting `unsafe-eval`). This triggers an in-depth review, and I'm guessing you're not explaining well why you need all this. In any case, I doubt this is an on-topic question: it's about a third party's review policies which we can only guess at.

Comment: But I am using an eval function and is important for the extension.

Comment: Then be prepared to explain. Also, what is your use for it? Do you load external code? If yes, that's another fat red flag, because then review can't review your code.

Comment: yes i am loading external code.

Comment: In that case I would say that your chances of getting this published are slim. You have "god mode" level permissions and intend to execute arbitrary code that Google can't see with that.

Comment: But many other extensions do the same how they got published?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207520/discussion-between-hr-312-and-xan).

Comment: hi @Xan i removed the eval and now the extension is left with just the broad host permission which is due to `<all_urls>` and the google is continuously rejecting it. I can't remove `<all_urls>` permission as my solution is based on that. Kindly check my updated manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google now requires you, the developer, to provide an explanation of what your extension does (according to [Single Purpose Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose)) and an explanation of why specific permissions are needed.

This is on the Privacy tab of the ["new" Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/)'s listing:
[image: Privacy UI]

Until those fields are filled out, Web Store blocks publishing of new extensions and updated versions of existing extensions.

On the plus side: it doesn't mean you have failed a review *yet.* So with good explanations you may be able to get this published. In your particualr case though, those are broad permissions + arbitrary code execution. It will be tough.

Comment: hi @Xan i removed the eval and now the extension is left with just the broad host permission which is due to <all_urls> and the google is continuously rejecting it. I can't remove <all_urls> permission as my solution is based on that. Kindly check my updated manifest.

Comment: I am unable to assist further in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
"version": "1.0",
```

Instead of

```
"version": "0.01",
```